# Build a field in the Select Q

Tags: sql, select, oracle10g

I am trying to add a field in my Select statment that will create a field with my desired output or make the field results empty.  My Boss doesn't want to scan the entire mopdescription field if they have to.

Please see code ** to see if you can make sense of this question/request.

```
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 
**UPPER(MOPACTIVITY.MOPDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%FTTT%'
OR UPPER(MOPACTIVITY.MOPDESCRIPTION) LIKE '%VZW%' AS "NOTE_DISP"**,
MOPACTIVITY.MOPDESCRIPTION
 FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
```

Comment: Your query doesn't appear to make a lot of sense.  To start with, I'm guessing that you want the two conditions to be in the `WHERE` clause not in the `SELECT` list. Assuming that is the case, then I would guess that your boss is concerned about scanning the `MopActivity` table (scanning a column isn't something that makes sense conceptually).  If both of those assumptions hold, then the problem comes that you can't use a regular index with leading wildcards. Are the leading wildcards actually necessary?  If so, are the search conditions fixed? Or are users entering `FTTT` and `VZW` in a form?

Comment: I am actually wanting it in the select and not the where.  The where is going to filter out the condition too but I want the area of interest set into the field "Note_Disp" of the querry.

Comment: And no, they aren't fixed into the form.  The end user is keying into a mass notes field.  I am trying to keep the boss from reading the entire note field unless said word is found in the description field.

Comment: Then I'm even more confused.  Do you want `NOTE_DISP` to be some sort of boolean?  Or a string representation of a boolean?  Or the value in the `MopDescription` column?  If you want it to be the value from the column, and your `WHERE` clause is already filtering out the rows of interest, why is there any need to do any sort of transformation in the `SELECT list?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  mopid
,       CASE
            WHEN INSTR(UPPER(mopdescription), 'FTTT') > 0
            THEN SUBSTR(mopdescription, INSTR(UPPER(mopdescription), 'FTTT'))
            WHEN INSTR(UPPER(mopdescription), 'VZW') > 0
            THEN SUBSTR(mopdescription, INSTR(UPPER(mopdescription), 'VZW'))
            ELSE NULL
        END AS note_disp
FROM    mopuser.mopactivity';
```